# Reference.cs missing some classes when adding an asmx WCF Service Reference. Why? How to fix?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, asmx, web-reference

It was not happening when using Web Reference in old .NET Frameworks. It auto generates with success but when i look into it, it has more lines although it is short of some classes i need to use.

Comment: What does the specific error message say? You can add the missing references to the project based on the error message.

Comment: No error message. Those classes are missing comparing to old Frameworks Reference.cs. I was using them. The generate tool must has changed but it should not act like this.